# A variant of a geometric series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

It is clear that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n ar^k$ converges if $|r|<1$.

Is it true that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n a_k r^k$ converges if $|r|<1$ and $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} a_k$ converges?

If so, how can I prove this?

Comment: If there exists $\lim_k a_k$ then $(a_k)$ is bounded. That is, there exists $a$ such that $|a_k|\le a, \forall k.$

Comment: Your variant is a very special type of series called a "Power Series".  Google it.